# How to get Pester Mocks working in a script

Tags: powershell, pester

I not able to get Pester 5.5.0 Mocks working. I have defined a `Mock` for `Get-Date` in the `Describe` block but when the tests run it does not appear to be invoked.

**MyFunction.ps1**

```
function Get-CurrentDate {
    return Get-Date
}
```

**MyFunction.test.ps1**

```
BeforeAll {
    . $PSCommandPath.Replace('.Tests.ps1', '.ps1')
}

Describe 'Get-CurrentDate Tests' {
    Mock Get-Date { return [DateTime]'2023-01-01' }

    It 'returns the mocked date' {
        $expected = [DateTime]'2023-01-01'
        $actual = Get-CurrentDate
        $actual | Should -Be $expected
    }
}
```

Output:

> Invoke-Pester .\MyFunction.Tests.ps1
>
> Starting discovery in 1 files. Discovery found 1 tests in 1.92s.
> Running tests. [-] Get-CurrentDate Tests.returns the mocked date 2.24s
> (2.03s|213ms)  Expected 2023-01-01T00:00:00.0000000, but got
> 2023-11-27T16:42:33.7602327+01:00.  at $actual | Should -Be $expected,
> C:\MyFunction.Tests.ps1:12  at ,
> C:\MyFunction.Tests.ps1:12

Is the problem the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pester 5 Mocks need to be defined either in a `BeforeAll`, `BeforeEach` or in the `It` block itself. This should work:

```
BeforeAll {
    . $PSCommandPath.Replace('.Tests.ps1', '.ps1')
}

Describe 'Get-CurrentDate Tests' {
    
    BeforeAll {
        Mock Get-Date { return [DateTime]'2023-01-01' }
    }

    It 'returns the mocked date' {
        $expected = [DateTime]'2023-01-01'
        $actual = Get-CurrentDate
        $actual | Should -Be $expected
    }
}
```

Note also that Mocks are now scoped based on their placement: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking#mocks-are-scoped-based-on-their-placement

> Mocks are no longer effective in the whole Describe / Context in which they were placed. Instead they will default to the block in which they were placed.